# Don't work laravel $request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Ajax response!

Don't work:

```
$request->input('fio');
$request->fio;
```

Worked only

```
$request->all();
```

But i need to access single values.

```
Object {
    fio: "Illya Yaremchuk",
    email: "zzzzz@sssss.com",
    _token: "A4bGMcklDoj4VrMzFk0qIKtVlYuX5U9o" }
```

Comment: How do you send ajax parametrs ?give me result of dd($request)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do read [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#retrieving-input) thoroughly (RTM!), its all there, optionally open up [API page](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/index.html).

You can access single values by using `get()` function of `Request::class` as:

```
$request->get('key_name');
```

or if you need default value you may use following:

```
$request->get('key_name', 'default');
```